# Как правильно переопределить свойство одного БЭМ-блока в другом?

Tags: html, css, бэм

У меня имеется такой БЭМ-блок:

```
.panel {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Он довольно универсальный и используется на проекте во многих местах. Теперь появилась потребность на его основе создать блок `.alert` по такому типу:

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel alert alert_error">
  Invalid value
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.alert_error {
  background-color: red;
}

.alert_success {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Проблема тут в том, что я вынужден для алерта изменять одно свойство, определенное для `.panel`: `background-color`. И мой вопрос в том, как это сделать правильно.

С одной стороны, я не нуждаюсь в модификаторах `.panel_error` и `.panel_success`, ведь эти категории относятся исключительно к `.alert` и в других местах проекта не используются. С другой стороны, в документации БЭМ [сказано](https://ru.bem.info/methodology/redefinition-levels/), что для случаев переопределения свойств какого-либо компонента мы должны создавать файл с тем же именем, что имеет исходный, где компонент изначально определен, и только там переопределять свойства. Очевидно, это рекомендуется для того, чтобы не забыть, что у нас имеется переопределение, и в `index.css` можно было явно и наглядно импортировать переопределяющий файл сразу после исходного. Короче говоря, это означает, что переопределять `background-color` внутри `alert.css` нежелательно, ибо со временем все забудут, что там что-то переопределено и изменение порядка импорта однажды может сломать стили.

Пока я остановился на таком решении, что в папке `alert` у меня лежит два файла: `panel.css` и `alert.css`, и таким образом я ясно вижу переопределение. Однако такой подход приводит к усложнению селекторной специфичности, приходится писать `.panel.alert_success` (ведь я не хочу, чтобы соответствующий `background-color` распространился на другие `.panel`), а также к неудобному разделению стилей одного по сути блока на два разных файла.

Каково самое "чистое" возможное решение в данном случае?

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не  завести какой-то отдельный класс для состояний?

```
.status {background: inherit}    
.status_complete {background: green;}
.status_error {background: red;}
```

Comment: Такой подход действительно возможен, но только ваш ответ необходимо дополнить тем, что мы в этом случае должны убрать определение свойства `background-color` из `panel.css` и `alert.css` (иначе проблема с первенством импортирования сохранится)

Answer (score 0):

У вас получается два блока связанных друг с другом. Если `panel` изменится, то и все `alert` будут изменены.

Так как `panel`содержит две строки, то нет ничего плохого в том, чтобы скопировать их в класс `alert` и не использовать `panel`. Так как `alert` используется с модификатором, то можно скопировать только свойство `border`

В результате получим:

1. Алерты не зависят от панели
2. Будет один блок навешен и не испортится семантика в шаблоне

```css
.alert {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.alert_error {
  background-color: red;
}

.alert_success {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert alert_error">
  Invalid value
</div>
<div class="alert alert_success">
  Valid value
</div>
```

Comment: В том то и дело, что к сожалению в реальном проекте `.panel` это гораздо больше, чем просто border и мне бы хотелось, чтобы ее стили изменялись в одном месте, распространяясь на `.alert`. Я пока остановился на том, что просто изменяю `background-color` для `.alert` и все. Такой подход возможен коль скоро `.alert` реализован в виде компонента web-фреймворка (для его стилей гарантируется увеличение селекторной специфичности), но может привести к описанным выше проблемам в другом случае.

Comment: Я бы все равно,  рекомендовал дублировать стили и отказаться от panel. Можно через миксин. Тем самым специфичность будет низкой. Сильно большой проблемы с дублированием кода я не вижу.  Также alert будет независим от panel. Тем более вы поместили panel в папку alert, что тоже не правильно